# Why this Ant/Ivy integration of CXF WSDLToJava does not work?

Tags: java, ant, cxf, ivy, wsdl2java

I would like to use `WSDLToJava` of [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) in my [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) buildfile to create Java code from a WSDL. The dependencies are resolved using [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). I always get the following error:

```
WSDLToJava Error: Could not find jaxb databinding within classpath
```

I do not have an installation and want to use Ivy to do the job for me. Here is the part of my Ant buildfile:

```
<target name="generate" depends="init">
  <ivy:retrieve conf="build"/>
  <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/generated"/>
  <ivy:cachepath pathid="build-classpath" conf="build"/>
  <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true">
    <arg value="-d"/>
    <arg value="${basedir}/target/generated"/>
    <arg value="-client"/>
    <arg value="${basedir}/src/schema/MyWebService.wsdl"/>
    <classpath refid="build-classpath"/>
  </java>
</target>
```

I use Java 6, Ant 1.8, Ivy 2.2.0 ant CXF 2.2.12. In the Ivy module I configured the following:

```
<configurations>
  <conf name="build" visibility="private"/>
  ...
</configurations>

<dependencies defaultconfmapping="*->default">
  <dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws" rev="2.2.12" conf="build"/>
  <dependency org="org.apache.cxf" name="cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb" rev="2.2.12" conf="build"/>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

Where is the problem? Maybe there is a dependency missing, but which one? Without Ivy, the Ant integration uses a classpath with all jars of the CXF installation. If I do so, it works.

In the output of the build I see the following:

```
generate (2s)
[generate] ivy:retrieve (1s)
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolving dependencies :: me#mine;1.0
[ivy:retrieve] confs: [build]
[ivy:retrieve] found org.apache.cxf#cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws;2.2.12 in public
[ivy:retrieve] found org.apache.cxf#cxf-tools-common;2.2.12 in public
[ivy:retrieve] found oro#oro;2.0.8 in public
[ivy:retrieve] found wsdl4j#wsdl4j;1.6.2 in public
[ivy:retrieve] found com.sun.xml.bind#jaxb-xjc;2.1.13 in public
[ivy:retrieve] found com.sun.xml.bind#jaxb-impl;2.1.13 in public
[ivy:retrieve] found javax.xml.bind#jaxb-api;2.1 in public
[ivy:retrieve] found javax.xml.stream#stax-api;1.0-2 in public
[ivy:retrieve] found javax.xml.soap#saaj-api;1.3 in public
[ivy:retrieve] found org.apache.cxf#cxf-api;2.2.12 in public
[ivy:retrieve] found org.apache.cxf#cxf-common-utilities;2.2.12 in public
... (many more) 
[ivy:retrieve] :: retrieving :: me#mine
[ivy:retrieve] confs: [build]
[ivy:retrieve] 32 artifacts copied, 28 already retrieved (8959kB/38ms)
[generate] mkdir
[mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/target/generated
[generate] java (1s)
[java] WSDLToJava Error: Could not find jaxb databinding within classpath
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb` dependency that you likely need as well.   For a variety of reasons, the tooling and runtime are separate for JAXB.

Comment: Thanks, I only need `cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws` and `cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb`